# How to make circular button in kivy using button behavior?

Tags: python, kivy

I think there is a way to do it in kivy rather than going round the python code.

my code in the kv file:

```
ButtonBehavior:
     source: "round-icon.png"
```

the app crashes saying

> AttributeError: 'ButtonBehavior' object has no attribute
>   'register_event_type'

`round-icon.png` is circular icon. The last thing that I will appreciate recommendation, How to set this button to certain size is the window?

Answer (score 1):

Try importing Image also:

```
Image+ButtonBehavior:
     source: "round-icon.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a custom *rule*(/class) that has the behavior and you need to include `Image` as el3phanten stated, yet it won't work only that way, because it'll return you a missing class.

Kv language creates a widget from either already registered classes, or custom classes, which may be Python + Kv (that thing you define in both files), or kv only(dynamic). I guess your intention is the dynamic one, so I'll go this way:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
<Test@ButtonBehavior+Image>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, .3
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
BoxLayout:
    Button:
    Test:
        source: 'image.png'
"""

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

The behavior needs to be **first** similar to inheriting in Python, then you may add another parts, such as `Image`.

There's however a big problem for you in this implementation, which is visible with the `Rectangle` in my example. That is an area that captures every touch, which means you might have a circular **image**, yet the touch are is still a **rectangle**.

To get around that you'll need to check for a collision, thus you need to switch from dynamic class to the one that's defined even in Python, so that you can make [custom collisions](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/customcollide.py). [Example](http://yehar.com/blog/?p=2926).

That, however, might be really costly even for a single button, therefore a better solution is using something like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image

kv = """
<RoundButton>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, .3
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            size:
                [self.size[0] - root.OFFSET_x,
                self.size[1] - root.OFFSET_y]
            pos:
                [self.pos[0] + root.OFFSET_x / 2.0,
                self.pos[1] + root.OFFSET_y / 2.0]
BoxLayout:
    Button:
    RoundButton:
        source: 'image.png'
        on_release: print('Release event!')
"""


class RoundButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    OFFSET_x = NumericProperty(100)
    OFFSET_y = NumericProperty(200)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        left = touch.x >= self.pos[0] + self.OFFSET_x / 2.0
        down = touch.y >= self.pos[1] + self.OFFSET_y / 2.0
        up = touch.y <= self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - self.OFFSET_y / 2.0
        right = touch.x <= self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - self.OFFSET_x / 2.0

        if left and down and up and right:
            print('collided!')
            self.dispatch('on_release')
        else:
            print('outside of area!')


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

or a really low number of points to a better area coverage, yet higher than for a simple rectangle.

> How to set this button to certain size is the window?

Use `size_hint` or directly `Window.size` to manipulate your widget's size. `size_hint` is definitely better unless you want to have everything in Window, i.e. without any proper [Layout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html)

Comment: OMG,  I think that this solution is smarter than me :). It has been 4 hours or something where I am trying to manipulate the code to understand how did you get this solution! Generally, It don't sense any of the code, but he part which really irritates me is that of on_touch_down() method. I literally don't understand any of the code below it. Again it's smarter than me and I hope that kivy make a better solution

Comment: @omarPython there are three basic methods for user's input (and more, but these are the basics): on_touch_down, on_touch_move and on_touc _up. You should find them in kivy.uix.widget docs. The down method gets as a parameter `touch`, which is just a position where a user clicks/taps e.g. (10, 20). Offset is only a number you substract from the area where the touch belongs, which by default is the Widget's area (can be something else too). The blue area is the final area after the substraction, which will accept the touch and if the touch isn't present there, it's just ignored in your function.

Comment: If this doesn't help you, you might want to draw a rectangle on a paper - that's a widget with touch area and size X and Y. Offset is a number substracted from both sides, therefore substract half from left and from right (same for Y). Draw the smaller rectangle accordingly. That's your final touch area in the "if" block in on_touch_down.